# TestFlight not sending invite to internal users

Tags: testflight

I have an app uploaded to the App Store but not submitted. I want to test with internal testers (me) and under the app’s TestFlight pane I have the one build which is indicated as “Testing”. When I click on the build and go to “App Store Connect Users” my email is listed as “invited” with the option to resend the invite.

But I haven’t received the invite and it’s not showing up in my TestFlight.

I’ve also tried adding myself in the external tester area but when I select my name in “add existing testers” window, “next” remains disabled.

I uploaded the app with an ad hoc provisioning profile, that may be the problem? I’m actually only aiming to use the app myself, so if there’s an easier way to use the existing ad hoc provisioned upload without fixing this while TestFlight issue I’d welcome that as well.

Thanks for the help!